# How do I enable Time Machine local snapshots on an iMac?

Tags: backup, time-machine, imac, external-disk, high-sierra

I have an iMac with a Fusion drive running High Sierra. Time Machine is enabled and backs up to an external disc.

Time Machine takes daily [local snapshots](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015) so that you can go back to a specific day, even if you don't plug in your backup disc every day.

Unfortunately, this feature is enabled only on laptops, as the aforelinked page says.

How do I tell Time Machine to enable it on my iMac? I plug in my external disc only once a fortnight to backup, but I'd still like to go back to a particular day's snapshot, say if I overwrote a file.

Comment: It used to be `sudo tmutil enablelocal` but this doesn't work anymore in High Sierra.

Comment: What version of macOS? Is your iMac running pure SSD or a spinning HDD either as fusion drive or just a HDD?

Comment: @bmike High Sierra with a Fusion Drive. Sorry I forgot to include that information earlier.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that local snapshots are enabled automatically in High Sierra.

[image]

The text in the red box translates to "local snapshots, as long as disk space is available".

I didn't find something from Appe on this, but [this blogpost](https://www.jethrocarr.com/2017/11/06/macos-high-sierra-unable-to-free-disk-space/) comes to the same conclusion.